# How to remove white space showing on top of scrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I have the following scrollView. Everything works exactly as I want, except: there is a white space between the top of the scrollView and the top of the ImageView. What I want is for the image to be flushed at the top. It would be great too if the scrollView does not scroll past the bottom edge of the image as well. Thanks for all suggestions.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/welcome"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/welcome_page" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: i don't know what "white space" you are referring to (maybe some pic? ) but did you try adjustViewBounds?

Answer (score 1):

To remove the top space, try using

```
android:scaleType="fitStart"
```

in the ImageView. As for the bottom space removal, maybe someone else can help you with that.

Comment: ok so this worked. but I need to limit the scrollable height of the scrollview so that once the bottom of my image is reached, the scrollview should stop scrolling. Right now it does for a whole additional screen height. Thanks +1.

Comment: I figured how to remove the bottom height by setting the ImageView to a fixed height instead of the wrap_content.

Comment: Actually I was wrong about that fix: it only worked on my Galaxy S5. When I tried running it on my LG (android api 16) it still showed the bottom space.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:layout_marginTop="-2sp"` to your `LinearLayout`. This will move **LinearLayout** a bit higher, hiding the space.

Comment: The space I am talking about is about a whole screen tall. And I want something more systematic than some magic number: unless that magic number could somehow be guaranteed to work well on all devices. This is android after all.